# Función de la instrucción SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transacciones

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de entender de una manera más sencilla las funciones de la instrucción **SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL** pero no llego a hacerlo lo que encuentro no me llena en la sencilles que quiero por eso acudo aquí ¿Puede alguno decirme de la forma más sencilla que se pueda las funciones de esta instrucción?, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voy a intentar resumir un poco el tema, pero te recomiendo que leas la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql) y también [este articulo](http://www.guillesql.es/Articulos/SQLServerFAQ_Aislamiento_Transaccion_Isolation_Level.aspx) ya que es un tema crítico en la configuración del servidor.

**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL**: esta configuración establece el nivel de aislamiento de las transacciones, es decir el grado en que se aísla una transacción de las modificaciones de datos realizadas por otras transacciones. Es una configuración muy importante ya que afecta directamente el rendimiento de la base por el tipo y los tiempos de bloqueo que se establecen.

Las opciones son:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL  
    { READ UNCOMMITTED  
    | READ COMMITTED  
    | REPEATABLE READ  
    | SNAPSHOT  
    | SERIALIZABLE }
```

#### READ UNCOMMITTED

Permite hacer "lecturas sucias" (dirty reads), es decir permite leer los cambios realizados en una transacción que aún no han sido confirmados (commit). En el caso que una transacción 1 actualice una fila, la transacción 2 va a leer el valor modificado aunque la transacción inicial no haya sido "commiteada", en el caso que se haga un `ROLLBACK`, las consecuencias son importantes: podemos haber obtenido registros que ya no existen más, o datos totalmente distintos. Se suele usar en situaciones muy controladas.

#### READ COMMITTED

Asegura integridad en la lectura, solo se leerán registros que efectivamente fueron "commiteados", esto obviamente no asegura que múltiples lecturas de uno o más  registros dentro de una transacción siempre retornen los mismos valores, los datos son libres de ser modificados mientras dure la transacción. Esto se conoce como "lecturas no repetibles", es decir, la transacción 1 podrá leer un registro en su primer lectura que sea distinto al leído en la segunda. Esta es la configuración por defecto de SQL Server.

#### REPEATABLE READ

Asegura "lecturas repetibles" e impide las "lecturas sucias", imaginemos el ejemplo anterior, la transacción 1 bloqueará los recursos hasta haber completado las dos lecturas, ambas lecturas obtendrán los mismos datos, pero la transacción 2 quedará a la espera de la liberación de la 1 para poder completarse. De todas formas no evita el caso de las "lecturas fantasma", que ocurren cuando al hacer un `SELECT` de un intervalo de datos, en el medio de la transacción otro proceso inserta registros dentro de dicho intervalo.

#### SERIALIZABLE

Este nivel evita las "lecturas no repetibles", las "lecturas sucias" y las "lecturas fantasma". Para estas últimas, una transacción en este nivel puede bloquear el rango de datos leídos o eventualmente toda la tabla para asegurar que otra transacción no inserte registros sobre el rango leído.

#### SNAPSHOT

De la misma forma que el modo `SERIALIZABLE` evita las "lecturas no repetibles", las "lecturas sucias" y las "lecturas fantasma", pero a diferencia de la anterior, en vez de usar un mecanismo de bloqueo, genera "versiones" de los datos leídos en la `TEMPDB`, de manera que cada transacción leerá una versión de los datos acorde al instante en que se ejecuta. Esto puede eventualmente ocasionar que exista mas de una "versión" de un mismo dato, y no se evitan conflictos de actualización, cuando una transacción 1 lee un registro para luego modificarlo, si en el medio otra transacción 2 modifica el mismo dato, la transacción 1 generará un error y un `ROLLBACK` automático.

#### READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT

No es exactamente un nivel de aislación, es una mezcla de **READ COMMITTED** y **SNAPSHOT**, utiliza el versionado de filas pero no evitan "lecturas no repetibles" ni "lecturas fantasma", se configura la propiedad en el servidor `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` y se usa el aislamiento `READ COMMITTED`.

En lineas generales, cuanto mayor consistencia asegure una transacción en sus operaciones, mayor es la cantidad de recursos que requiere del motor, y a medida que aumenta la concurrencia, mayor cantidad de bloqueos y degradación del rendimiento.